# How to find YouTube Channel name for a Deleted video channel if you have a link to one of the video?

Tags: youtube

How can I found the YouTube Channel name of this video? The Video is unavailable (YouTube shows message that video is unavailable as the account is terminated). Also TheWayBackMachine don't have Snapshot (It does have one snapshot which is also unavailable).

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9A91idibgT0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: If you search for the Video ID (the part after `youtube.com/watch?v=` and before any `&something=somethingelse`), you often can find YouTube downloaders and pseudo-mirrors which may or may not contain the meta data you're looking for.

In this specific case, while I couldn't find the channel name, I did find the original on the CCC website: [https://media.ccc.de/v/30C3_-*5552*-*en*-_saal_g_-*201312291130*-_india_s_surveillance_state_-_maria_xynou](https://media.ccc.de/v/30C3_-_5552_-_en_-_saal_g_-_201312291130_-_india_s_surveillance_state_-_maria_xynou)

Comment: Yeah I download the video from CCC Website.. Thanks for the link..